# Using python to create a bindSkin in Maya

Tags: python, maya, skinning

I am trying to create a script that would help me automate the creation of a spine rig, but I am running into a problem. I am following the tutorial provided [here](https://www.3dtotal.com/tutorial/1838-maya-rigging-introduction-to-rigging-a-human-torso-by-jahirul-amin-body-animation?page=2) and I am working on the step where you skin the curve to the IK joints.

However, when I try to use mc.bindSkin(), I keep getting an error:

```
Error: RuntimeError: file[directory]/maya/2016.5/scripts\createRigSpine.py line 200: Maya command error)
```

It's too late right now to for me to do much experimenting, but I was hoping someone could help me, or tell me if I'm using the wrong commands.

```
mc.select(crvSpine, jntIkMidSpine, jntIkChest)
mc.bindSkin(crvSpine, jntIkMidSpine, jntIkChest, tsb=True)
```

(have also tried mc.bindSkin() and mc.bindSkin(tsb=True))

Ideally, I want the settings to be:

```
Bind To: Selected Joints
Bind Method: Closest Distance
Skinning Method: Classic Linear
Normalize Weights: Interactive
```

Edit: I wanted to use skinCluster, not bindSkin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use the [skinCluster command](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/skinCluster.html) to bind your curve to the joints - and you can actually do it without selecting anything!

Try this:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

influences = [jntIkMidSpine, jntIkChest]
scls = mc.skinCluster(influences, crvSpine, name='spine_skinCluster', toSelectedBones=True, bindMethod=0, skinMethod=0, normalizeWeights=1)[0]

# alternatively, if you don't want such a long line of code:
#
influences = [jntIkMidSpine, jntIkChest]
kwargs = {
    'name': 'spine_skinCluster',  # or whatever you want to call it...
    'toSelectedBones': True,
    'bindMethod': 0,
    'skinMethod': 0,
    'normalizeWeights': 1
}
scls = mc.skinCluster(influences, crvSpine, **kwargs)[0]

# OR just use the short names for the kwargs...
#
influences = [jntIkMidSpine, jntIkChest]
scls = mc.skinCluster(influences, crvSpine, n='spine_skinCluster', tsb=True, bm=0, sm=0, nw=1)[0]
```

If you wanted to, you could also explicitly set the weights you want for each cv of the curve.  You could use the `skinPercent` command, or even just use `setAttr` for the various weight attrs in the skinCluster (that's a little more difficult, but not much)

Comment: hmmm.... looks like I started answering this and proof-reading/verifying my code around the same time you posted about the skinCluster command - didn't notice you had found it, but glad you did!

Comment: Thanks. That's a bit more complete than the solution I provided.

Comment: glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

`cmds.bindSkin()` command made for binding bones to geometry. It's not suitable for binding to IK's only. So you need to assign what `joint` you need to bind to.

For example:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

mc.select('ikHandle1','nurbsCircle1','joint5')
mc.bindSkin('ikHandle1','nurbsCircle1','joint5')

# the order of selection is vital
```

For constraining selected objects use the commands like this:

```
mc.pointConstraint('ikHandle1','nurbsCircle1', weight=5.0)
```

To find out what constraints are available to you, use `Rigging module` – `Constrain menu` – *Parent, Point, Orient, Scale, Aim, Pole Vector*.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong command. mc.skinCluster is what I wanted to use, not mc.bindSkin.